# when creating story or bug - how do i force the creator to add a parent link to the workitem

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

We are using process template xml to define our azure devops workitems.
i am looking for a way to require a user to add parent link (feature work item) whenever he/she creates a bug or user story.
is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops . No such rule is provided in the XML process model to force the creator to add a parent link to the work item. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-field?view=azure-devops-2020#add-rules-to-a-field). In addition, Related Work represents link type, not a field, so the rule also cannot be applied to Related Work.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22), which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.